# Python Dataframe Filter data using linear relation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame with input and output columns. They have a linear relation. So, I want to remove data that does not fit this relation. My actual df is big and has many samples. Here, I am giving an example.

My code:

[image]

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'ip':[10,20,30,40],'op':[105,195,500,410]})
```

I am not getting any idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a linear fit first then filter out the data that is outside of a certain threshold.
Sample code below:

```py
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ip':[10,20,30,40],'op':[105,195,500,410]})

# do a linear fit on ip and op
f = np.polyfit(df.ip,df.op,1)

fl = np.poly1d(f)

# you will have to determine this threshold in some way
threshold = 100

output = df[(df.op - fl(df.ip)).abs()<threshold]
```

Comment: When there are large samples and significant outliers, don't you think outliers can influence the fit as well?

Comment: @Mainland Yes, outliers can influence the fit. But if you have a large sample size and the linear correlation is clear, then the outlier influence can be ignored. However, if your data have large numbers of "outlier", then the linear correlation is not clear. But if you have a pre-determined linear relation that you know, you can use that linear function to filter. In the end, it boils down to what is the correct way to define the "outlier" in your specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

You can create a boolean mask to check the ratio of op/dp is less then their mean value:

```
m=xdf.eval("op/ip").lt(xdf.eval("op/ip").mean())
```

Finally:

```
out=xdf[m]
plt.scatter(x=out['ip'],y=out['op'])
```